# sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW never executed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a sqlite in my app , and everything seem to be ok , but i database method the while loop is not executed , and i can't get the result from query. Could somenone help me? Any help will be apreciate !

I also create a copy for databse, as i saw in other answer for other questions .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    int sqlite3_open(const char *filename, sqlite3 **database);

    sqlite3 *contactDB; //Declare a pointer to sqlite database structure
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"verbeGeo" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"DB is open");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DB can be open");
    }


    NSString *querySQL = @"select id from conjugare where rowid=1";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1,
                           &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Statement prepared successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Statement preparation failed");

        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB), sqlite3_errcode(contactDB));
    }

    sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    [self database];
       }

-(void)database{

    sqlite3 *contactDB;
    NSString *querySQL = @"select id from conjugare where rowid=1";

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);


    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *idNumber =
        [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
         (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sqlite3_open` statement is initializing the `contactDB` variable defined in `viewDidLoad`.  The `contactDB` variable defined in `database` is local to that method and not initialized.

1) Either make `contactDB` an instance variable or pass it to `database`.

2) Check error returns for all calls (e.g. `sqlite3_prepare_v2` in the `database` method).

Comment: Thank you very much . I made contactDB an instance variable and it's work.